# A-Frame appendChild works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to create new entities dynamically in A-Frame using template elements. The helper function looks like this:

```
function htmlToElement(html) {
    const template = document.createElement('template');

    // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result.
    html = html.trim();

    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.firstChild;
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('loaded', () => {
  const cube = htmlToElement('<a-box position="0 1 -2"></a-box>')

  document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(cube);
});
```

This works great in Firefox, but in Chrome the entity doesn't show up. If look at the entity with something like `document.querySelector('a-box')` there is no `object3D` property, so I don't think appending the element to the scene is registering the element with A-Frame on Chrome. What am I missing to get this to work in Chrome? Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/twastvedt/pen/MXgBWW?editors=1011).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try using insertAdjacentHTML?  You may not need the template wrapper then.

Comment: Nice. Yes, this works: `document.querySelector('a-scene').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<a-box position="0 1 -2"></a-box>');`

Answer (score 2):

Template behavior with innerHMTL may vary. You can use `createContextualFragment`. To dump raw HTML for A-Frame, do:

`el.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(str));`

Comment: tried to get into it, but only found out setting the `innerHTML` creates a node using [createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). Any idea why on ff it creates the element with the `a-entity` constructor, and chrome just a plain node ? Is it just implementation details ?

Comment: I am not sure why. I ran into it with the state component iterative templating. Some combination with custom elements, polyfill, template implementation, innerHTML implementation, etc.

Comment: Both this and machenmusik's `insertAdjacentHTML` were new to me, and work great, though it looks like `insertAdjacentHTML` is even a little simpler, and possibly marginally [faster](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/) if you're using `'beforeend'`.

Comment: Though `insertAdjacentHTML` doesn't return the created node, so if you need a reference to the created node it looks like `createContextualFragment` is better.